# How to sort the row order according to number not character?

Tags: r

I want to sort the row order of the data frame according to number, not character. My row indices for my data frame are numeric with an order of `1,10,11,12,2,20,21,22`, etc. I have used `order()` trying to sort my row indices to `1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10`, etc, but my row indices just stayed the same.

So my data frame has 1 column with 11 rows:

```
structure(list(`colSums(fake_with_noise_boundary)` = c(-3405, 2304, 
-4096, 474, -2089, -3921, -2590, 1605, 1317, 2804, 2934)), 
row.names = c("1", "10", "11", "12", "2", "20", "21", "3", "30", "31" , 
"40"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: can you add `dput(your_data)` output to let us discuss about it ?

Comment: If those are actually strings instead of just numbers, then `order(as.integer(x))`. Your mention of "row indices" seems odd, can't really help without knowing more about your data. I "second" the request for `dput(your_data)`.

Comment: Does my edit make more sense?

Comment: I also want the corresponding row values to be changed according to the change of row number

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rownames` are always stored as characters, if you want to sort them according to their numeric value you can change it to numeric and `order`.

```
df <- df[order(as.numeric(rownames(df))), , drop = FALSE]
df

#   colSums(fake_with_noise_boundary)
#1                              -3405
#2                              -2089
#3                               1605
#10                              2304
#11                             -4096
#12                               474
#20                             -3921
#21                             -2590
#30                              1317
#31                              2804
#40                              2934
```

Comment: What if my row name starts with symbols like  `_`, and my row names have the following order: `c("_1.1", "_2.1","_1.5")`?

Comment: In that case, you can use `df <- df[order(readr::parse_number(rownames(df))), , drop = FALSE]`

Answer (score 1):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <-
structure(list(`colSums(fake_with_noise_boundary)` = c(-3405, 2304, 
                                                       -4096, 474, -2089, -3921, -2590, 1605, 1317, 2804, 2934)), 
          row.names = c("1", "10", "11", "12", "2", "20", "21", "3", "30", "31" , 
                        "40"), class = "data.frame")

df %>% 
  #Create a column with your rowname
  rownames_to_column() %>% 
  #Transform rowname to numeric
  mutate(rowname = as.numeric(rowname)) %>% 
  # Sort row order by rowname 
  arrange(rowname)

   rowname colSums(fake_with_noise_boundary)
1        1                             -3405
2        2                             -2089
3        3                              1605
4       10                              2304
5       11                             -4096
6       12                               474
7       20                             -3921
8       21                             -2590
9       30                              1317
10      31                              2804
11      40                              2934
```